# Dreams are made true or Dreams get “made true”?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

“Dreams don’t “come true”. Dreams get “made true”. — Robin S. Sharma.

I am confused, how can this be grammatically correct? It should be, Dreams are made true, and not Dreams get "made true".

Comment: This is perfectly grammatical (however inelegant) English; and the verb _get_ can take any participle: _get made, get carried, get baked,_ and even  _get gotten._

Answer (score 1):

Both statements

> Dreams *get made* true
>   Dreams *are made* true

basically have the same meaning, that

> Dreams can be true

the difference is "get made" has more emphasis on the process of becoming true, whereas "are made" is more a statement of fact that that's they way they are.

> These shirts *are made* blue.
>   *the color of the shirts are meant to be blue from the beginning*
>
> These shirts *get made* blue.
>   *the shirts may have started as a different color and were transformed to be blue*
>
> Dreams *are made* true.
>   *dreams start as being true from the very beginning*
>
> Dreams *get made* true.
>   *dreams can become true with something (hard work, perseverance, etc.)*

Answer (score 1):

Sharma is using parallelism here.

The author is a motivational speaker who is trying to explain that people shouldn’t be inert and wait for their dreams to come true. They will have more success if they take action.

*Dreams come true* is idiomatic language, so it makes sense that Sharma starts by negating that.

Your version:

> Dreams don’t come true. Dreams are made true.

is grammatical, but I don’t think it packs as much punch as Sharma’s version:

> Dreams don’t come true. Dreams get made true.

The verb *get* is more of an action verb than *are*, and the author is trying to spur us into action. The verb *get* has [several meanings](https://www.wordnik.com/words/get); I think the ones that match up closest with this quote are:

- to earn; to acquire as a result of action or effort

In a comment, P.E. Dant suggests this might be “inelegant.” I’d say that, if that’s true, it’s probably deliberately that way. The quote is designed to get us to think.